# Azure Sitecore WebApp 500 errors after config change

Tags: azure

I'm currenlty experiencing some problems with a basic Sitecore setup on Azure.
I deployed a simple XP0 environment with Powershell.

Then I made a change in the connectionstrings.config (Kudo) for manually switching between Azure Search and a VM Solr environment. The switch worked, the default site was running.

But when changing it back to the Azure Search, the site keeps giving me '500 - The request timed out.'

Even though I don't see any errors in the log. It seems like it is stuck somewhere, but I can't figure out what the cause is.

Anyone experienced similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my other answer merely fixed half of my problems and was inconsistent.
So I had to create a Sitecore support ticket.

After some investigation, they pointed me to a hotfix of a known Sitecore problem: **Deadlock causes site unresponsiveness on application start**.
If you are having similar problems, use Reference Number 209972 in a support ticket.
And download the hotfix from the [Knowledge Base article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/910936) to test if it fixes your problems.

Apparently this can occur since version Sitecore 9.0 Initial release.

Answer (score 4):

After testing out some more things, I finally was able to solve the problem.

I got closer to my problem by switching out the connection strings to databases of a clean setup. Which made the Sitecore environment work again without the 500 errors.

After further research I tried again with the databases that gave the problem. And my reaction was to check the EventQueue tables.
After cleaning up the EventQueue, History and PublishQueue tables, the site was responding again (no 500 errors anymore).

So if someone else comes across this problem, have a look at those tables.
Try switching databases perhaps or clean them in Core, Master and Web.
Article that helped me:
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/sitecore-event-queue-how-to-clean-it-and-why/